# LIBGDX Image tearing

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm making an game in libGDX and I have been noticing some image tearing when camera is moving. Note that it happens only when the game is maximized and the camera x position is less than screen width and camera y position is less than screen height. Here's a GIF showing what is the problem[image] The color errors are not the problem here, it is the GIF fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was to do with float rounding(or something to do with floats atleast). After casting them to ints it works without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling CPU sync and enabling vsync could fix your issue.

```
config.useCPUSynch = false;
config.vSyncEnabled = true;
```

There is more discussion of this [over on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/1avtc5/awful_screen_tearing_in_libgdx/) if that doesn't work.

Comment: `config.useCPUSynch` doesn't exist